# How to style select with form-control style so that it aligns on the left with input with form-control style?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I notice that if I use flexbox with a `select` and `input`, both with form-control style, that they **do not align on the left** (I have put that text in bold as people do not seem to understand the problem). The left side of the top input is not aligned with the left side of the select. They align if I remove the padding of the input.

**Edit**: This problem appears on Chrome and Safari. Firefox is okay.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2XAbwRmuwVYRnSsBXQ1K?p=preview)

[image]
Markup

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Input default</label>
    <input class="input form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Input no padding</label>
    <input class="input form-control no-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Select</label>
    <select class="input form-control">
          <option>Hello</option>
          <option>World</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  flex: 1
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
```

How can I style the select only or use flexbox so that it aligns with the input?

Please do not edit this question so that it runs a code snippet ***unless*** the output is exactly as shown in the image.

Comment: it is already aligning I guess?

Comment: @kukkuz The top input and the select do not align on the left.

Comment: The code in your question produces a layout in which the input and select do align. The only discrepancy might be the 1px difference in border-width between select and input. Could you create a working snippet or demo of the layout you are seeing in the picture?

Comment: @ovokuro They do not align at all on the left. You can even see that in ankita patel's answer.

Comment: To be fair, that people don't understand your problem is possibly a reflection on the way the question has been presented, or a difference in browser interpretation.

Comment: @ovokuro I've updated the question to include which browsers show the problem. I'm happy for anyone to edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: I looked at the snippet in Firefox and it is completely different. Using Chrome 61 everything looks aligned to me. On firefox all elements are out of alignment.

Comment: Strange. My browsers show the opposite. :-)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Bootstrap. Can you place the labels and inputs in a column with set width?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}
.col-form-label { 
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;   
}
.container { 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-xs-6 col-form-label">Input default</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
        <input class="input form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-xs-6 col-form-label">Input no padding </label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
        <input class="input form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-6 col-form-label">Select</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
      <select class="input form-control">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>World</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the select and input still don't align. The question is nothing to do with the labels.

Comment: @camden_kid now pls check label is align to input.

Comment: Could you please tell me how the left side of the top input is aligned with the left side of the select?

Comment: You want align in small screen..?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question to which browsers show the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't use flexbox. I have found an answer which I have added. I have updated the question to say that I would like to style the select only or use a flexbox solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add padding to select element because is generated by the user agent so you can use `appearance: none;` to reset browser default and add your style.
Unfortunately not all browser support it: https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  flex: 1
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

select.form-control {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Input default</label>
    <input class="input form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Input no padding</label>
    <input class="input form-control no-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">Select</label>
    <select class="input form-control">
          <option>Hello</option>
          <option>World</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with your snippet is that they now don't align on the right. :-)

Comment: Only under 767px. In this case is a `.container` issue

Comment: Someone edited the question with code snippet but it incorrectly showed the problem. You may have copied that.

Comment: If you want use flex why don't use bootstrap 4?

Comment: It's something we will adopt but not sure when.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to put the various elements within a flex wrapper. [This example shows the principle](https://plnkr.co/edit/5PcWOylHcFXiDTn6v9uw?p=preview).

[image]

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TDh7cckSay19nNRHhbt4?p=preview)

Markup

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <label class="label">Input default</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <label class="label">Select</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>World</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  flex: 1
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```